# Compare two files and update changed rows as well as add the new rows

Tags: python

I have two files, a master file and a new data file. The new data file is provided on a daily basis and contains the most up-to-date data. This can include duplicate rows already present in the master file, changed rows with some new values, and brand new rows.

How can I quickly get the master file updated with all changed/new rows?

**Example of desired output:**

Master File Contents:

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
1,LP,LETTER,14,False
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,LP,LETTER,18,True
4,LP,LETTER,20,False
```

New File Contents:

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,AU,LETTER,18,False
4,BR,LETTER,20,False
5,LP,LETTER,22,False
6,LP,LEDGER,24,False
7,LP,LEDGER,36,False
```

Final File Contents:

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
1,LP,LETTER,14,False
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,AU,LETTER,18,False
4,BR,LETTER,20,False
5,LP,LETTER,22,False
6,LP,LEDGER,24,False
7,LP,LEDGER,36,False
```

As you can see, row 2 was a complete duplicate, therefore deleted; rows 3 and 4 had some updated values which will be taken into the final output; and rows 5-7 were brand new and added to the final output.

Comment: Do you accept a solution with external library like `Pandas`?

Comment: Yes I originally was trying to achieve this using Pandas.

Comment: The ID is unique? This is a common key between two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Pandas, `concat` files then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('master.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('update.csv')

df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1]).drop_duplicates('ID').sort_values('ID').to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

`final.csv`:

```
ID,Format,Output,FontSize,isDefault
1,LP,LETTER,14,False
2,LP,LETTER,16,False
3,AU,LETTER,18,False
4,BR,LETTER,20,False
5,LP,LETTER,22,False
6,LP,LEDGER,24,False
7,LP,LEDGER,36,False
```